# How do I convert a relational database to owl using Java

Tags: java, database, owl

I want to build an ontology library through the relational database, how should I handle the automatic generation of owl files by the relational database?

Comment: did you search for relational database to OWL or RDF? I cannot believe that you couldn't find anything. What was wrong with those approaches like r2rml?

Comment: I used D2R, but the generated nt files didn't translate well into owl files

Comment: what does this mean? you can serialize any OWL ontology in N-Triples format. It's nothing more than serialization. The content can still be OWL. Most likely, you translation generates instance data, thus, it should be fine. Please be more specific, show sample data, sample mapping, sample output and the expected result or issues you (think you) have

Comment: I used D2R to generate the mapping files related to the database and transformed them into NT files or RDF files. Next, I want to convert the NT files or RDF files into owl files. But instead of using protege to manually convert RDF to owl.

Comment: I don't get it. The N-Triples file **is** just one serialization format of RDF and OWL. There is no difference compared to RDF/XML, Turtle or whatever. Any OWL ontology can be serialized as N-Triples file. Your N-Triples file already contains OWL axioms.

Comment: By the way, an "owl file" means what? Which syntax resp. serialization? You'll need the schema triples anyways, otherwise your instance data is useless

Comment: I want to convert it to owl, not owl/ XML to NT. I'll attach the RDF generation later.

Comment: Not sure if you understand me, but what is "owl" for you. One last try, you generate N-Triples via D2R. **this is OWL**, it is just one serialization format among others. You can convert this N-Triples file to other formats like RDF/XML, Turtle, whatever.